# Adding class to list elements based on custom attribute priority in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have couple of hours that i am struggling with this code. So, the scenario is having a menu navigation that will have a specific class depends on screen size but also i want this class to be triggered based on certain priority.

I have been successful so far with the screen detection and i am able to activate this class and hide the links, but not sure how i can prioritize it.

let me show some code so you can have a better idea.

This is the menu:

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="items in item track by $index">
    <a href="{{item.url}}">
        <span ng-class="{'active':isActivated}">{{item.name}}</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

so the active class is activated when the isActivated method it's true. Works just fine so far. If you see the code above i am already displaying the menu filtering by priority with the track by $index.

This is an example of the json file i am pulling menu items:

```
{
"name": "inbox",
"url": "http://google.com",
"icon": "fa fa-envelope",
"priority": 1

},
{
"name": "contact us",
"url": "http://yahoo.com",
"icon": "fa fa-phone",
"priority": 3

},
{
"name": "about us",
"url": "http://aboutus.com",
"icon": "fa fa-user",
"priority": 2

}
```

you can see the priority i am giving to prioritize the links. What i am not solving is how can i activate that isActivated method based on the same priority.

I will really need some advice on this and if it's possible a small examlpe how you will deal in this case.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the connection between `isActivated` and the priorities exactly? Which is the `same priority` you mention?

Comment: @Ori Drori there is no connection with priority on that method. For now isActivated is a method that based on certain screen size it switches to true. The ng-repeat is displaying these links based on priority you see on json file. As well i wanted to hide these items based on same priority. So basically let say we are in ipad mode i don't want to hide all of them but just the lowest priority and so on when switches to landscape or portrait mode. Thanks

Comment: That wasn't very clear from the question. I suggest to insert the info in the comment to the question. It looks so obvious suddenly :)

Answer (score 0):

Send `item.priority` as a parameter to the `isActivated` method:

```
$scope.isActivated = function isActivated(priority) {
// do whatever you do to decide if display or not using the priority
}

<li ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
    <a href="{{item.url}}">
        <span ng-class="{ 'active': isActivated(item.priority) }">{{item.name}}</span>
    </a>
</li>
```